# Python: How to concurrently write multiple strings to Command Prompt

Tags: python-3.x, concurrency, cmd

How do you write multiple strings in cmd at the same time in python 3.4.2? As in, you have two function that are running concurrently, and both are needed to constantly update and write strings to the screen. In my case, I have a downloader, where when search something, it downloads it, and updates the percent downloaded. I want to be able to go directly to the next search so I can see what I am typing in while the previous download is finishing.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "write strings in cmd." Do you mean print to stdout?

Answer (score 0):

If, by 'at the same time' you mean 'in one call', then

```
print(s1, s2, s3, sep=mysep)
```

or

```
sys.stdout.write(mysep.join((s1, s2, s3))
```

where mysep in '' or whatever separator you want.

Comment: Note that the first one requires `from __future__ import print_function` in Python 2.6 and 2.7.